# Convert Portrait to landscape build crash Titanium

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I have declared orientation mode "Portrait" in tiapp.xml Titanium file. That will working perfectly. 
I have one video player page that will always open in landscape mode. So for that I have set like this.

> var vidWin = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
>             title : 'Video View Demo',
>             backgroundColor : '#000',
>             orientationModes: [
>                 Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT,
>             ]
>         });

Its working perfectly for this page. But when I pressed back button of my android device and click on any navigation menu. Its shows NullPointerException.

Comment: Sorry for my previous answer it was based on native Android application, I am not aware of titanum

Comment: Man! you are the genius person. You save my life. I tried to changed on my titanium based on your reply.
Its work perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please put previous code again. That code can save someone life.

Comment: I have added my code back please note that particular answer is for native android you can relate this to your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your manifest

`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`

This is not the recommended way but you can try it out. And the reason behind this is your activity is created again when your orientation is changed and some object which are holding data are getting destroyed.

You can go through this [article](https://android.jlelse.eu/handling-orientation-changes-in-android-7072958c442a) for more details.

> Note:- This answer is based on native Android, as per  @Narayan Sharma
>   I have added my answer back, you can relate this to your application

Comment: where is manifest file in titanium.? Can you please help on this?